# geocoder gem not reading addresses

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, gmaps4rails, rails-geocoder

I have a model with a single address attribute. The address attribute is a string, so users can enter the full address using one address attribute. Will geocoder be able to generate the longitude or latitude from just one attribute or do I have to use several attributes such as zipcode, city and state if I want geocoder to generate the correct information?

The reason why I'm asking this question is because I tried to do it the single attribute way and geocoder does not return anything. Apparently, when I ran the debugger in the dashboard action, the code ran into an infinite loop when it try to get the vendor's latitude and longitude.

Method for the dashboard:

```
def dashboard        
  if params[:search].present?
    @vendors = Vendor.near(params[:search], 50)
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@vendors) do |vendor, marker|
    marker.lat vendor.latitude
    marker.lng vendor.longitude
    marker.infowindow vendor.discount_info
    marker.picture ({
      "url" => "assets/marker.png",
      "width" => 32,
      "height" => 32})
  end
  else
    @vendors = Vendor.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@vendors) do |vendor, marker|
      marker.lat 37.3352
      marker.lng -121.8811
      marker.picture ({
        "url" => "assets/marker.png",
        "width" => 32,
        "height" => 32})  
    end
  end  
end
```

Vendor model:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  geocoded_by :address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :address_changed?
end
```

Comment: I see at least an error in your code. You have an if with an else block, but you are closing the first block with and end. I don't really know why Ruby isn't issuing an error to this, but this is wrong anyway. Please check your logic.

Comment: I fixed that problem and the issue in this question

Comment: Great! Why don't you post the solution here? It will help other people in the future.